# Fullscreen slideshow with images, text and video

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm completely new at python, learned not much yet. My goal is, to build a slideshow app, which should display images, images with transparent text frames and also videos. Playing a video is my main problem at the moment.

A little test script with static content. Later, all content should be loaded from a web service.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkvideo as tv
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageTk
import time

# fullscreen window
window = tk.Tk() 
window.attributes('-fullscreen', True) 

# dimensions
window_width = window.winfo_screenwidth()
window_height = window.winfo_screenheight()
text_width = int(window_width * 0.4)
text_x = int(window_width - text_width)


# transparent rectangle for text
imgs=[]
def create_rectangle(x,y,a,b,**options):
    if 'alpha' in options:
      # Calculate the alpha transparency for every color(RGB)
      alpha = int(options.pop('alpha') * 255)
      # Use the fill variable to fill the shape with transparent color
      fill = options.pop('fill')
      fill = window.winfo_rgb(fill) + (alpha,)
      img = Image.new('RGBA', (a-x, b-y), fill)
      imgs.append(ImageTk.PhotoImage(img, master=canvas))
      canvas.create_image(x, y, image=imgs[-1], anchor='nw')
      canvas.create_rectangle(x, y, a, b, **options)


# fullscreen canvas
canvas = tk.Canvas(window, bg="white", bd=0)
canvas.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)


# only image slideshow
images = ['quiz1.jpg', 'quiz2.jpg', 'quiz3.jpg', 'quiz4.jpg']
for img in images:
    image = Image.open("/home/jpm/Bilder/" + img)
    newimage = image.resize((window_width, window_height))
    photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(newimage, master=canvas)
    canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor="nw", image=photo)
    canvas.update()
    time.sleep(5)


# image with text slideshow
images = ['1658724794aff.jpg', '1658724768kar.jpg']
headlines = ['Headline 1',
             'Headline 2']
paragraphs = [['paragraph 1',
               'paragraph 2',
               'paragraph 3',
               'paragraph 4'],
              ['paragraph 1',
               'paragraph 2',
               'paragraph 3',
               'paragraph 4']]
i=0
for img in images:
    image = Image.open("/home/jpm/Bilder/" + img)
    newimage = image.resize((window_width, window_height))
    photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(newimage, master=canvas)
    canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor="nw", image=photo)
    create_rectangle(text_x, 0, window_width, window_height, fill= "white", alpha=.80, width=0)
    head = canvas.create_text(text_x+20, 20, text=headlines[i], fill="#72B765", font=('Helvetica 34 bold'), anchor='nw', width=text_width-20)
    canvas.update()
    x0, y0, x1, y1 = canvas.bbox(head)
    for paragraph in paragraphs[i]:
        time.sleep(4)
        line = canvas.create_text(text_x+20, y1+10, text=paragraph, fill="#000000", font=('Helvetica 18 bold'), anchor='nw', width=text_width-20)
        x0, y0, x1, y1 = canvas.bbox(line)
        canvas.update()

    canvas.update()
    time.sleep(8)
    i = i + 1

canvas.destroy()

my_label = tk.Label(window)
my_label.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
player = tv.tkvideo("/home/jpm/Bilder/docsite_promotion.mp4", my_label, loop = 0, size = (window_width,window_height))
player.play()

window.mainloop()
```

The image and image with text parts running fine. My problem is the video. First of all, it is only displayed at the end of the script. If I put the Label with the video between the two loops or in front of the first, nothing is shown. I also found out, that the program is not waiting till the video ends.

It's all too confusing for me, to explain it better. Maybe I don't understand the flow control of python programs at all. Maybe tkvideo is not the best option. I played also with ffpyplayer, but can't find out, how use it with tkinter.

I only want to display these three types of content in any order and finally also in an endless loop.

Hope you understand me and can give me some tips.

Comment: `.play()` doesn't wait for end of video (it runs it in separated thread) and next image may replace it (hide it) before you see video. You would need use .after(millisecond, my_function)` to check periodically if there is end of video and later display images.

Answer (score 0):

`.play()` doesn't wait for end of video (it runs code in separated thread) and next image may replace it (hide it) before you see video.

I tried to use `sleep()` to wait for end of video but it makes problem - it raises error because `function` doesn't run in main thread.

You would need to use `.after(millisecond, my_function)` to check periodically if there is end of video and later display images.

If in `tkvideo` you use `self.thread` instead of `thread` then you can check periodically `self.thread.is_alive()` to catch end of thread. But this need also some method to run next code which will change images. First idea is to create function which changes images and send it as `callback` to function which check end of video - and it would run this `callback()` when `is_alive()` is `False`. But all this makes problem when you would like to create something more complex.

---

Here example which uses `window.after()` to check `self.thread.is_alive()` and later it runs `callback()`

I uses `tkvideo` from my other answer - I added `self.running` to have method to stop video in any moment.

```
import time
import tkinter as tk
import threading
from time import perf_counter, sleep
import imageio
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import os

class tkvideo():

    def __init__(self, path, label, loop=False, size=(640,360), hz=0):
        self.path = path
        self.label = label
        self.loop = loop
        self.size = size
        self.hz = hz
        self.running = True   # <-- variable to control loop

    def load(self, path, label, loop, hz):
        """
            Loads the video's frames recursively onto the selected label widget's image parameter.
            Loop parameter controls whether the function will run in an infinite loop
            or once.
        """
        frame_data = imageio.get_reader(path)

        if hz > 0:
            frame_duration = float(1 / hz)
        else:
            frame_duration = float(0)

        if loop:
            while True:
                before = perf_counter()
                for image in frame_data.iter_data():

                    frame_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.fromarray(image).resize(self.size))

                    if not self.running:   # <-- variable to control loop
                        return             # exit function and stop thread

                    label.config(image=frame_image)
                    label.image = frame_image

                    diff = frame_duration + before
                    after = perf_counter()
                    diff = diff - after
                    if diff > 0:
                        sleep(diff)
                    before = perf_counter()
                print('[load] end of loop')
        else:
            before = perf_counter()
            for image in frame_data.iter_data():
                frame_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.fromarray(image).resize(self.size))

                if not self.running:   # <-- variable to control loop
                    return             # exit function and stop thread

                label.config(image=frame_image)
                label.image = frame_image

                diff = frame_duration + before
                after = perf_counter()
                diff = diff - after
                if diff > 0:
                    sleep(diff)
                before = perf_counter()
            print('[load] end of loop')

    def play(self):
        """
            Creates and starts a thread as a daemon that plays the video by rapidly going through
            the video's frames.
        """
        
        # uses `self.thread` instead of `thread` to have access to `self.thread.is_alive()`
        self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self.load, args=(self.path, self.label, self.loop, self.hz))
        self.thread.daemon = True
        self.thread.start()


def show_video(filename, size, callback=None):
    global player
    global my_label

    fullpath = os.path.join(folder, filename)

    my_label = tk.Label(window)
    my_label.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

    player = tkvideo(fullpath, my_label, loop=False, size=size)
    player.play()

    # check after 5ms
    window.after(5, check_end_video, callback)

def check_end_video(callback):
    global my_label

    if player.thread.is_alive():   # check if it end of thread
        # check again after 5ms
        window.after(5, check_end_video, callback)
    else:
        # remove label
        print('The End')
        my_label.destroy()

        # run next function
        if callback:
            callback()

def show_image(filename, size, callback=None):
    global my_label

    fullpath = os.path.join(folder, filename)

    frame_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(fullpath).resize(size))

    my_label = tk.Label(window)
    my_label.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

    my_label['image'] = frame_image   # show image on label
    my_label.image = frame_image      # solution for bug in PhotoImage

    # check after 5000ms (5s)
    window.after(5000, check_end_image, callback)

def check_end_image(callback):
    global my_label

    # remove label
    print('The End')
    my_label.destroy()

    # run next function
    if callback:
        callback()

def other_function():
    button = tk.Button(window, text='Close', command=window.destroy)
    button.pack(fill='both', expand=True, padx=250, pady=250)

# --- main ---

folder = "/home/jpm/Bilder/"

window = tk.Tk()
window.update()

#window.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
#window_width = window.winfo_screenwidth()
#window_height = window.winfo_screenheight()

window.geometry('800x600+800+300')
window_width = 800
window_height = 600

# ---

size = (window_width, window_height)

# run video and it will later run `show_image`
show_video("docsite_promotion.mp4", size, 
            lambda:show_image('quiz1.jpg', size, other_function))

# ---

window.mainloop()
```